# What does the actual angular js controller object contain?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I am a pretty new computer science student with a good amount of experience in C++, but I am just getting started with Javascript.

I've been trying to understand how Angular Js works and I'm a little stuck on controllers. I understand the basics of how they can be used, but I can't decipher the syntax for how they are constructed and what they actually are.

The w3 tutorial states that "A controller is a JavaScript Object, created by a standard JavaScript object constructor."

And the syntax for creating a controller is:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
});
```

What part of this code is the object constructor?
I might be completely wrong, but to someone inexperienced in javascript it looks like the "controller" function of the app object is being called with 'myCtrl' and 'function($scope){} as parameters.

Can anyone explain to me what the second line of this code is actually doing and why those parameters are passed to it?

Also where/what is the actual controller object? If I wanted to physically log the controller object how would I refer to it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood the concept.In AngularJs controller is function but when you bind that controller to DOM element using ng-controller on that time you are binding object of that controller to your html DOM element.

Anf for second line: **app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
});** by writing this line you are registering your controller named "myCtrl" to your module.by this way you are telling AngularJs that this is my controller.

There are so many ways you find online to register your controller.

1)

```
 app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

      $scope.xyz="This is myCtrl"

    });
```

2)

```
function myCtrl($scope){

        $scope.xyz="This is myCtrl"
     };

     app.controller("myCtrl",myCtrl);
```

Also make sure whichever name you give in first parameter in **app.controller("","")** .by that name your controller is registered in your module.

Comment: Thanks for your help! For the first way of registering the controller, what is the actual name of the object though? Like if I wanted to log the controller object using console.log what would I type?

Comment: I think you need to read the concept of object oriented programming (oops) in javascript. then you can create the object of controller and log the object.             Also you can use available different tool like "ng-inspector" or "batarang"   for logging.These are great tools for logging in angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

[Angularjs Controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) handles your logic, like handle user input, output and other stuff like API call, other calculation etc.

Controller takes two arguments 1) Controller name and 2) Function to be handle

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
});
```

So now in above code

`var app = angular.module('myApp', []);`

Using this line you define your app module

`app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  //Your login for controller is here
 });`

Above code says you define controller `myCtrl` for your `app`

you can declare variable or function using `$scope` which is only accessible to only `myCtrl` scope. You can't use it outside that controller.

You can declare variable using $scope as following
`app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myVar = "Hello World";
 });`